# I am installing DFX. The installation was successful but when I ask the dfx --version it says permission denied. How to fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, internet-computer

[image]

I was about to begin learning about blockchain, DApp and Internet Computer. I was installing the necessary things in my PC. When I began to install dfx, it was successfully installed, but when I asked for the version it said permission denied how to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you know how to check its permissions? Try that first. It looks like you don't have read access.

Comment: Also, beside the point, but why did you add the executable path to the `PATH` variable? Was that in the installation instructions? I ask because the `PATH` should contain only directories, not regular files.

Comment: Firstly, I don't know how to check permissions. Secondly, yes, it was in the installation instructions regarding PATH variable. @wjandrea

Comment: To start, run `ls /usr/local/bin/dfx` and edit the output into the question. LMK when you do. FWIW, on second thought, it doesn't seem to be read access. I'm guessing it's actually missing execute access.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Thank you everyone. Happy to inform that the issue was resolved.
I just typed:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dfx
```